# Do I need to dispose of a DbContext if it was created from an ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I made some extension methods for counting related records and I don't want to explicitly pass the DbContext, so instead I get the ObjectContext and create a DbContext from it.

Will the new DbContext get disposed when the original DbContext is dispose?

```
var original = new CustomDbContext("connectionString")
var entity = original.Table.First()

// in the extension method
var objectContext = entity.GetObjectContext()
var newDbContext = new CustomDbContext(objectContext, false)
// dispose of newDbContext??

// original caller
original.Dispose()
```

Comment: Did some testing and the DbContext created from the ObjectContext is unusable once you dispose of the original connection. ("The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.")

Answer (score 1):

After some more researching, testing and checking the source code for DbContext I came to the conclusion that is not required.  The DbContext only needs to dispose of the internal context which is a wrapper for the ObjectContext that is passed.

If you dispose of the DbContext that owns the ObjectContext, the new DbContext will essentially be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a new DbContext from object context. When setting the dbContextOwnsObjectContext to 'true' the ObjectContext is disposed when the DbContext is disposed, otherwise the caller must dispose the connection.

By setting it to false as you have, the new DbContext would not be disposed

**EDIT**

This spools up that objectContext separately from the dbContexts

```
        var objectContext = new ObjectContext("connectionString");
        var newDbContext1 = new CustomDbContext(objectContext, false);
        var newDbContext2 = new CustomDbContext(objectContext, false);

        newDbContext1.Dispose();
        newDbContext2.Dispose();
        objectContext.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting since having it set to false led to it not being disposed (like you said) but unusable (Exception being that the ObjectContext was disposed). Would you recommend setting it to true then?

Comment: Setting it to true, disposing of the new context would dispose of the old context. Guess having it set to false would be best for my use case and I wouldn't need to dispose the new dbcontext.

Comment: OIC... are you creating multiple DBContexts from a single ObjectContext, which is created from an init DBContext create? You'll want to create a 'root' type ObjectContext and then spool up DBContext from that single Object Context...

Comment: Yeah, except one of the DbContext was actually the owner. Disposing of the owner would dispose of the connection used on the second hand objects. Which is what I hoped would happen.  Thanks.